selenium chrome. python couldnt find the button on the website
im working with selenium and tried to click on the button with id "device-upload-button" on reddit. Code just cant find and click on it. I tried with xpath, id, classes
this is my code, firstly it opens profile in adspower and gets to the reddit websit
    settings = read_settings()
    api_key = settings['api_key']
    profile_id = settings['profile_id']
    subs_list = settings['subs']
    subs_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'subs')

    subs = [subdir for subdir in os.listdir(subs_folder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(subs_folder, subdir))]

    open_url = "http://local.adspower.com:50325/api/v1/browser/start?user_id=" + profile_id
    close_url = "http://local.adspower.com:50325/api/v1/browser/stop?user_id=" + profile_id

    resp = requests.get(open_url).json()
    if resp["code"] != 0:
        print(resp["msg"])
        print("please check ads_id")
        sys.exit()
    time.sleep(3)

    chrome_driver = resp["data"]["webdriver"]
    service = Service(executable_path=chrome_driver)
    chrome_options = Options()

    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", resp["data"]["ws"]["selenium"])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

    try:
        for subreddit in subs_list:
            if subreddit not in subs:
                print(f"Subreddit '{subreddit}' not found in folder '{subs_folder}'. Skipping.")
                continue

           

            post_url = f'https://www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}/submit/?type=IMAGE'
            post_url1 = f'http://www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit}'

            sub_folder = os.path.join(subs_folder, subreddit)
            photo_files = [f for f in os.listdir(sub_folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(sub_folder, f))]
            sub_folder = os.path.join(subs_folder, subreddit)
            photo_path = os.path.join(sub_folder, photo_files[0])

            time.sleep(1)

         

            driver.get(post_url)
            print(f"Opened post URL for subreddit: {subreddit}")
            clickable_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                                      "//a | //button | //input[@type='submit'] | //input[@type='button']")

            for element in clickable_elements:
                element_id = element.get_attribute("id")
                if element_id:
                    print(f"Element ID: {element_id}")

            time.sleep(2)


    finally:
        pass
        # print("All operations completed")



Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example The code in your question cannot be executed outside of your personal environment
